# Are there any Early Church Fathers, Doctors of the Church or Catholic Saints who believed the world would possibly end by a comet hitting the earth?

Tags: catholicism, eschatology, early-church, prophecy, doctor

**Are there any Early [Church Fathers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Fathers) or Doctors of the Church or Catholic Saints who believed the world would possibly end by a comet hitting the earth or coming in close contact with it?**

The other day, I heard about NASA’s attempt to deflect a comet that might be on a collision course with the bright blue planet we live on. If this comet hits us, it could possibly alter the way we live on earth.

I doubt the asteroid will hit the earth, but my unwelcoming question stands.

> NASA predicts that the massive asteroid will pass by Earth on December 11, just a month and a few days from now. The asteroid has been classified as 4660 Nereus, and NASA does consider it very hazardous. The organization says that the asteroid is almost three times the size of a football pitch — roughly the size of the Eiffel tower.
>
> While it could be hazardous if it hits the Earth, NASA says the asteroid will fly by the planet at a distance of roughly 3.9 million kilometers. That distance is ten times greater than the area between the Earth and the moon, so it shouldn’t cause any issues on our planet. In the past, scientists have considered missions to the asteroid, but have never gone through with them.
>
> Eleanor F. Helin originally discovered 4660 Nereus in 1982. Nereus is just one of several asteroids included in the Apollo group. All of the asteroids in this group are known for passing close to the Earth as it orbits the sun.
>
> The asteroid orbits the sun every 664 days. However, scientists predict that it won’t come close to the Earth again until March of 2031. After that, it’s expected to come close again in 2050, though its closest approach isn’t predicted to arrive until February of 2060, roughly forty years down the line. As is the case with next month’s pass, however, neither of those passes are expected to be close enough to pose any risk of impact. - [NASA is tracking a 1,000-foot-tall asteroid that’s headed towards Earth](https://bgr.com/science/nasa-is-tracking-a-1000-foot-tall-asteroid-thats-headed-towards-earth/)

In case no Early Church Father or Doctor of the Church can be found to hold this possibility, are there any historical canonized saints of the Catholic Church who have predicted such a possibility?

Comment: Why do you think they would? Disturbances of nature ([Mt. 24:29](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=24&l=29-#x)) and the universal conflagration (which won't annihilate but only transform the earth) are signs preceding Christ's Second Coming. (Also, the astronomy at the time of the Church Fathers up until _circa_ 17th cen. thought comets were atmospheric phenomena.)

Comment: @Geremia Does St. Hildegarde ring a bell!

Answer (score 1):

**Are there any Early Church Fathers or Doctors of the Church or Catholic Saints who believed the world would possibly end by a comet hitting the earth or coming in close contact with it?**

It seems **St. Hildegard of Bingen** (1098- 1179 AD) did so.

Several saints have prophesied about a future three days of darkness and although I could only find St. Hildegard of Bingen at the moment for her prediction concerning a future comet hitting the earth, I believe there are other saints and/or blesseds to have done so.

St. Hildegard of Bingen Also known as the **Sibyl of the Rhine** is also a Doctor of the Church. She is well known for her visions.

> [**Hildegard of Bingen**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hildegard_of_Bingen) (1098 – 17 September 1179), also known as Saint Hildegard and the Sibyl of the Rhine, was a German Benedictine abbess and polymath active as a writer, composer, philosopher, mystic, visionary, and as a medical writer and practitioner during the High Middle Ages. She is one of the best-known composers of sacred monophony, as well as the most recorded in modern history. She has been considered by many in Europe to be the founder of scientific natural history in Germany.
>
> It was between November 1147 and February 1148 at the synod in Trier that Pope Eugenius heard about Hildegard's writings. It was from this that she received Papal approval to document her visions as revelations from the Holy Spirit, giving her instant credence.
>
> On 10 May 2012, Pope Benedict XVI extended the veneration of Saint Hildegard to the entire Catholic Church in a process known as "equivalent canonization," thus laying the groundwork for naming her a Doctor of the Church. **On 7 October 2012, the feast of the Holy Rosary, the pope named her a *Doctor of the Church.*** He called Hildegard "perennially relevant" and "an authentic teacher of theology and a profound scholar of natural science and music."

She made various comments about the end times, and also foretold that the world not know peace until the thone of France is regained by the 'white flower', the fleur de lys.

She foretold that a Monarch will come after some horrific catastrophic events and that a great comet will strike the earth and cause apocalyptic devestation. This could possibly be a prophecy of how the Three Days of Darkness will come about.
She also foretells that the Monarch will come after some horrific catastrophic events – a great comet will strike the earth and cause apocalyptic devestation – possibly, this could be a prophecy of how the ***Three Days of Darkness*** will come about.

Here is what she had to say:

> “The time is coming when princes and peoples will reject the authority of the Pope. Some countries will prefer their own Church rulers to the Pope. The German Empire will be divided. Church property will be secularized. Priests will be persecuted. After the birth of Antichrist heretics will preach their false doctrines undisturbed, resulting in Christians having doubts about their holy Catholic faith. Toward the end of the world, mankind will be purified through sufferings. This will be true especially of the clergy, who will be robbed of all property. When the clergy has adopted a simple manner of living, conditions will improve…”
>
> “At this time as a punishment for their sins Christians especially will attempt armed resistance to those who at that time are persecuting them, sensing no concern for the death of their bodies. A powerful wind will rise in the North carrying heavy fog and the densest dust by divine command and it will fill their throats and eyes so they will cease their savagery and be stricken with great fear. Then within the Christian people the Holy Godhead will accomplish signs and wonders as if accomplished them at the time of Moses with the pillar of cloud and as Michael the archangel did when he fought the heathen for the sake of the Christians. Because of Michael's help God's faithful children will march under his protection. They will decimate their foes and achieve victory through God's power…As a result of this a large number of heathens will join Christians in true faith and they will say: “The God of the Christians is the true God because such wondrous works have been accomplished among the Christians…”
>
> “**Before the Comet comes**, many nations, the good excepted, will be scoured with want and famine. The great nation in the ocean that is inhabited by people of different tribes and descent by an earthquake, storm and tidal waves will be devastated. It will be divided, and in great part submerged. That nation will also have many misfortunes at sea, and lose its colonies in the east through a Tiger and a Lion.” The Comet by its tremendous pressure, will force much out of the ocean and flood many countries, causing much want and many plagues. [After the] great Comet, the great nation will be devastated by earthquakes, storms, and great waves of water, causing much want and plagues. The ocean will also flood many other countries, so that all coastal cities will live in fear, with many destroyed. All sea coast cities will be fearful and many of them will be destroyed by tidal waves, and most living creatures will be killed and even those who escape will die from a horrible disease. For in none of these cities does a person live according to the laws of God. Peace will return to Europe when the white flower again takes possession of the throne of France. During this time of peace the people will be forbidden to carry weapons and iron will be used solely for making agricultural implements and tools.  Also during this period the soil will be very productive and many Jews, heathens and heretics will join the Church. Peace will return when the Lily ascends the Throne again. The land will be very productive . During this time weapons will be forbidden. Iron will only be used for agricultural tools. In this period the land will be very productive. Jews, heathen and heretics will join the church… .”
>
> “After that there will be so few men left that seven women will fight for one man, that they will say to the man: “Marry me to take the disgrace from me.” For in those days it will be a disgrace for a woman to be without child, as it was by the Jews in the Old Testament … .”
>
> [**The Great Catholic Monarch and Angelic Pontiff Prophecies**](https://greatmonarch-angelicpontiffprophecies.blogspot.com/p/st-hildegard-of-bingen.html?m=0)

[St. Hildegard's 12th C. ***comet prophecy***](https://St.%20Hildegard%27s%20End%20Times%20Prophecy%20of%20a%20Comet%20Striking%20Earth%20(3%20Days%20of%20Darkness)) can also be read about in the book entitled: "*The Prophets and Our Times*”, by  Fr. Culleton,
Pages 139-140, 1941 A.D. Imprimatur.

Also, keep watch for the asteroid Apophis on Friday, April 13th, 2029!

- [God of Chaos asteroid more dangerous than NASA admits! Apophis update!](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FcsEe534lpM)

Comment: Given her claim that "Peace will return when the Lily ascends the Throne again," was her prophecy dated to a time of French monarchy? Also, by saying, "God's faithful children will march under [Archangel Michael's] protection. They will decimate their foes and achieve victory" does that not speak of Crusade-type thinking? Were her prophecies dated and, if so, have those dates passed with failure of her foretelling?

Comment: @Anne I think that  we will have to wait until the possibility that the prophecy has been fulfilled or that circumstances may have been play out differently. Time will tell.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any Early Church Fathers, Doctors of the Church or Catholic Saints who believed the world would possibly end by a comet hitting the earth?
>
> are there any historical canonized saints of the Catholic Church who have predicted such a possibility?

Would ancient itinerant rabbis count as such ?

> <sup>Matthew 24:29</sup> Immediately after the tribulation of those days shall the sun be darkened, and the moon shall not give her light, and *the stars shall fall from heaven*, and the powers of the heavens shall be shaken.

> <sup>Mark 13:25</sup> And *the stars of heaven shall fall*, and the powers that are in heaven shall be shaken.

How about fishermen ?

> <sup>Revelation 6:13</sup> And *the stars of heaven fell unto the earth*, even as a fig tree casteth her untimely figs, when she is shaken of a mighty wind.